# Is it bad practice to populate lots of data in a constructor?

Tags: java, concurrency, constructor, hashmap

Is it bad practice to do all data importing in a constructor? Or would a static factory method be more suitable that creates the object, populates it, and then returns it?

There are definitely objects I want intitialized with all data ready to go, such as data-driven singletons like extended Hashmaps that ingest data from a database upon construction. I figured this approach is better than lazy initialization especially in concurrent environments. But am I doing something wrong?

```
class MyHashMap extends HashMap<MyKey, MyObject> 
{
    private MyHashMap() { 
         populateFromDb();
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you expose `this` pointer before construction (probably to multiple threads)?

Comment: That would be something I'd strive not to do since partially constructed objects should never escape. Let's just assume all constructor operations like populateFromDb() does not let any references of "this" escape

Comment: You may start *pre-fetching* data in the constructor.

Comment: What do you mean "pre-fetch"?

Comment: @Thomas N.: start loading data (in separate thread) from database and return "this". When the data is required, wait up for the thread to be completed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If everything belogns to the state of the created object, there is nothing "wrong" with that.

However, from an architectual point of view you should have some place where all the businesscode runs. And this is the place, where you issue the database connection and read the data. You could even write a seperate class for performing the population task.

Reason:

There might be some point where you wanna replace the population mechanism by something else. For example in a Unit Test you might want to populate the data with some hard coded test data, so you don't need a database for the unit test.

Comment: i agree. factory is a great pattern for that, and check also the builder pattern.

Comment: Okay I think I will prefer static factory methods then.

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically nothing is wrong in having a bulky constructor. But maybe some creational design pattern like factory would help. Joshua Bloch - in his book Effective Java-  suggests factories over constructors and builders over big parameterized constructors. The builder pattern allows you to create an object in steps. Do you need all the data at once?